# CUDA: cuMemsetD32 on an unsigned int buffer fails due to arguments in an invalid range

Tags: cuda, memset

I want to reset (set to 0) a buffer of type unsigned int. I don't know why but for me only the cuMemsetD8-version works. Here is my code:

```
CUdeviceptr pBuffer;
cuMemAlloc(&pBuffer, sizeof(unsigned int) * 1000);
cuMemsetD32(pBuffer, 0, sizeof(unsigned int) * 1000); // fails with invalid argument (range) error
```

Comment: Important is, that if you use the D8-version instead of the D32-version using for example 3 as input you would set an unsigned int element to 0x03030303

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third parameter of [cuMemsetD32](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDA__MEM_g983e8d8759acd1b64326317481fbf132.html) is the number of *elements*, not the number of *bytes*. So
it should be:

```
CUdeviceptr pBuffer;
cuMemAlloc(&pBuffer, sizeof(unsigned int) * 1000);
cuMemsetD32(pBuffer, 0, 1000);
```